# How can we define a validation rule on fields of a SQL query MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

This is the SQL query.

```
SELECT Assets.Asset_ID, 
       Assets.Name,  
       Assets.[Purchase Price], 
       Assets.Salvage, 
       Assets.[Life Span], 
       Assets.[Accumulated Depreciation], 
       (Assets.[Purchase Price]-Assets.Salvage)/Assets.[Life Span] AS Current_Depreciation, 
       Current_Depreciation+Assets.[Accumulated Depreciation] AS Total_Depreciation, 
       Assets.[Purchase Price]-Total_Depreciation AS Net_Value
FROM Assets;
```

Since Total depreciation is derived (calculated) from purchase price, salvage and lifespan, i don't want it to exceed the purchase price. i.e. Total Depreciation <= Purchase Price. If that is the case Total Depreciation must be made equal to purchase price.
How to do this in SQL query itself in MS ACCESS 2007 because VBA cant be used for doing this on a query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "iif". See the guidance [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IIf-Function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3) for more details. I've added a brief example.

```
iif([Total Depreciation] < [Purchase Price], [Total Depreciation], [Purchase Price])
```